# Rails / Scope search on joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord, scope

Attempt to setup a lightweight search engine, having no problems setting up scopes on the model with it's own attributes.   Having some roadblocks on getting a joined table to play nice

```
       scope :seniority, -> (seniority) { where seniority: seniority }

       # merged scopes
       scope :edu, -> joins(:candidate_schools).where("candidate_schools.degree = #{edu}") }
```

Seniority works fine as it is a normal attribute.   My ultimate goal is to render user objects back from an associate table such as

```
     http://localhost:3002/api/v1/users?sector=tech&seniority=jr&edu=master
```

Where passing params for "edu", would be searching the "candidate_schools" table and filtering based on the "degree" attribute,  if the edu params match a record it would process a "user" object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your scope to this:

```
scope :edu, -> (edu) {
  joins(:candidate_schools).where("candidate_schools.degree = ?", edu) 
}

# usage
User.seniority("jr").edu("master")
```

Don't do `"candidate_schools.degree = #{edu}"`, look into [sql injection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection) for why.